# Are there any nontrivial solutions to $\prod_{i=1}^{k_a}\ln a_i=\prod_{j=1}^{k_b}\ln b_i?$ for all $a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{Z}^+$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, prime-numbers, logarithms, integers

**Context:** I have been exploring generalizing the notion of primes to hyper-operations. I define the first hyper-operation as addition
$$a\circ_0b=a+b,$$
and inductively define
$$a\circ_{n+1} b=\exp(\ln a\circ_n\ln b).$$
Thus $a\circ_1b=a\times b$ is the standard multiplication. This deviates from the "standard" hyper-operations for $n>1$, as $\circ_2$ is *not* exponentiation, but is instead the so-called [powerlog](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ofy2Kw2sIZg&ab_channel=EpicMathTime). The benefit is that $\circ_n$ is associative and communitive for all $n$.

---

**Primality definition:** Finally, for some set $X$ closed under $\circ_n$, for any $a,b\in X$, I define $a\circ_n b$ to be $n-\text{prime}$ iff
$$a\circ_n b=c\circ_n d \iff \{a,b\}=\{c,d\}\ \ \forall c,d\in X.$$

For example, the $1-\text{primes}$ in $(\mathbb{Z}^+,\circ_1)$  are the traditional primes.

---

**Question:** Consider some set $X$ over $\circ_2$ defined informally by
$$\begin{align}
(1)&\ n\in\mathbb{Z}^+\implies n\in X\\
(2)&\ a,b\in X\implies a\circ_2 b \in X\\
(3)&\ \text{only elements made by (1) and (2) are in }X
\end{align}$$
In other words, for any $a_1,\cdots,a_k\in \mathbb{Z}^+$, we have that $\exp\prod_{i=1}^k\ln a_i \in X$. So my question is

> What are the $2-\text{primes}$ in $X$?
>
> I believe what this boils down to is that, conversely, for any two sequences $(a_i)$ and $(b_j)$ where $a_i,b_j\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ for all $i\in\{1,\cdots,k_a\}$ and $j\in\{1,\cdots,k_b\}$, are there non-trivial solutions to
> $$\prod_{i=1}^{k_a}\ln a_i=\prod_{j=1}^{k_b}\ln b_i?$$

These would certainly give rise to non-$2-\text{primes}$. By nontrivial, I am discounting solutions which contain $\ln 1$ such as
$$\ln a\cdot \ln 1 = \ln b\cdot \ln 1,$$
or those which simply contain a different ordering such as
$$\ln a\cdot \ln b = \ln b\cdot \ln a.$$

---

**My work:** Initially, it would seem that the $(2-\text{primes})=X$, as I haven't found any examples of non-$2-\text{primes}$. Even the special case of $k_a=2$ and $k_b=1$ is pushing my proving abilities. I.e; are there nontrivial whole-number solutions to
$$\ln a \ln b = \ln c \iff a^{\ln b} = c?$$
My intuition tells me no; but proving it is another box of frogs. Perhaps the Gelfond–Schneider theorem helps?

Comment: What about $\ln 16 \cdot \ln 2 = 4 \cdot \ln 2 \cdot \ln 2 = (2 \ln 2)^2 = (\ln 4)^2$?

Comment: @VTand ahh that is a good example.